# Why doesn't my exported csv file contain list contents?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, oauth-2.0, spotipy

I'm somewhat new to python and trying to write a program using Spotipy to first get Spotify song IDs from a playlist and then grab info on their sonic characteristics. I'm able to grab a list of dicts containing the song IDs using a while loop, but if I understand correctly the list stays in the while loop.

In that case the next step would be to either save to a variable outside the loop or just export that info to a csv or other file. I'm opting to export for now, though my exported csv files seem to contain just the header "song_id" and not the actual song IDs themselves. I'm sure this is a simple error but I can't seem to spot what it is. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy
from pprint import pprint
import csv

sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())

#get songs from the Pop Connoisseur Playlist
pl_id = 'spotify:playlist:5AvWMqi0lbzSPvDR6WWesu'
offset = 0

while True:
    response = sp.playlist_tracks(pl_id, offset=offset, fields='items.track.id,total')
    pc_tracks = [x['track']['id'] for x in response['items']]
    print(pc_tracks)
    offset = offset + len(response['items'])
    print(offset, "/", response['total'])
    s = 0
    with open('popconn.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['song_id']
        thewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)
        thewriter.writeheader()
        for song in pc_tracks:
            s += 1
            thewriter.writerow({'song_id': song})

    if len(response['items']) == 0:
        break
```

Comment: You should probably move the `with open()` line above your while loop. Each time it is overwriting the `popconn.csv` file (not appending to it).

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I just did some messing with it and couldn't seem to get it to work without an error. To clarify: you mean the full with open() line:

    with open('popconn.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['song_id']

...and you mean to put it before the while loop even starts, OR the first thing INSIDE the loop?

Comment: To clarify, try moving from `with open...` to `...writeheader()` above your `while`. You will need to change the indentation. That bit only needs to be done once.

Comment: Ok, great - I'll give it a try. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is writing to the same file each time it goes around the `while True` loop. This would overwrite anything you have already written. As your last loop probably has no items, this will leave you with a file containing just the header.

To avoid this, you only need to open your output file once before you start your loop. This would also just write the header once.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy
from pprint import pprint
import csv

sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())

#get songs from the Pop Connoisseur Playlist
pl_id = 'spotify:playlist:5AvWMqi0lbzSPvDR6WWesu'
offset = 0

with open('popconn.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['song_id']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    thewriter.writeheader()

    while True:
        response = sp.playlist_tracks(pl_id, offset=offset, fields='items.track.id,total')
        pc_tracks = [x['track']['id'] for x in response['items']]
        print(pc_tracks)
        offset = offset + len(response['items'])
        print(offset, "/", response['total'])
        s = 0

        for song in pc_tracks:
            s += 1
            thewriter.writerow({'song_id': song})

        if len(response['items']) == 0:
            break
```

Comment: Ah yes, this worked like a charm! And the code was very handy; I didn't realize you meant that the while loop had to be indented *within* the with, though of course when I think about it now it seems obvious.